# how to know resource from which a bean is loaded in spring project.

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring framework. I am trying to know the list of xml files that are referenced while loading the beans.

By writing a class that is ApplicationContextAware, i am able to view the list of beans with :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring/sample-testcontext.xml")

public class SampleClass implements ApplicationContextAware {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {

        for (String beanName : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println("BeanName " + beanName);
        }
    }
}
```

But i want to know from which configuration files the beans are loaded.

Say "sample-testcontext.xml" contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">


    <beans:import resource="classpath*:spring/sample-testOneMorecontext.xml"/>
</beans:beans>
```

I want to know list of file names from which beans are loaded as "sample-testOneMorecontext.xml" and "sample-testcontext.xml".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you want to do that exactly? I am not sure that the internal implementation keeps a record of that information once the context has loaded. However, there is a way to know from which *resource* a particular bean has been loaded. That can be useful if you have several bean definitions with the same name and you want to know which one has "won".

Taking back your example (btw, you don't need to implement `ApplicationContextAware` since you are autowiring it)

```
@ContextConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring/sample-testcontext.xml")
public class SampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = context.getBeanFactory();
        for (String beanName : context.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(beanName + " --> "+  beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName).getResourceDescription());
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you something like (excluding the internal post processor bean definitions that the default implementation may register automatically)

```
beanFirst --> class org.SampleTest$Config
beanSecond --> class path resource [foobar.xml]
```

Where `beanFirst` was loaded from an inner class of the test (called `Config`) and `beanSecond` was loaded from a file called `foobar.xml` at the root of the classpath.