# How can we know the resource from which a bean is loaded in Micronaut?

Tags: micronaut

I use the below method in Spring Framework on BeanDefinition interface to debug :

```
@Nullable
String getResourceDescription()
```

Return a description of the resource that this bean definition came from (for the purpose of showing the context in case of errors).

It would be helpful if there's a parallel to this functionality in Micronaut.

Comment: "Return a description of the resource that this bean definition came from" - Can you provide some examples of values that would make sense as a description specifically in the context of Micronaut's DI container?

Comment: I had taken that statement from documentation(I should have formatted it better) - 

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html#getResourceDescription--

Comment: In the context of Micronaut -I hope to understand when there are multiple beans being initialized, being able to know which configuration(in some file) is driving instantiation of each bean. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215575/how-to-know-resource-from-which-a-bean-is-loaded-in-spring-project

Comment: "In the context of Micronaut -I hope to understand when there are multiple beans being initialized, being able to know which configuration(in some file) is driving instantiation of each bean." - Generally you don't have a configuration file driving instantiation of a bean with Micronaut's DI container.  This is why I am asking for what it is you think would be good examples of what a method like this would return.  If we understand that, we can look at possibly implementing it, or pointing toward a way to get that info now.

Comment: A use-case I encountered recently was a class annotated with Factory was producing some beans of the same interface but different data providers. I was also mocking those beans in a test class. When I logged bean definition names I could see multiple implementation beans of the same Interface. When I use Primary and MockBean on my mock implementation I could still find the beans not getting replaced. After a lot of debugging, I figured the factory class had to be replaced with a mock. Being able to map Bean to a file/resource would help in debugging such problems.

Comment: There is no association between a bean in Micronaut and a resource or file such as an XML file. A bean can originate from a particular JAR file, I don't know if that is the information you are after, but there is nothing else beyond that to create such as an association

Comment: I guess any information about the resource (jar/configuration yaml) where the bean instantiation is based on could be of help in debugging because beans are mostly configuration driven.